# the subject of the sub clause

Tags: phrases, sentence, syntactic-analysis

> Supplier shall also provide Purchaser without restriction full and
>   accurate information regarding locations, contact names, and numbers
>   for any known occurrences of infringement upon Supplier Intellectual
>   Property by any suppliers or vendors of goods or Components for the
>   Products, as well as finished or semi-finished Products worldwide
>   immediately upon learning of such infringements.

in the above sentence,is "numbers" also for "finished or semi-finished Products worldwide immediately upon learning of such infringements."namely,
"Supplier shall also provide Purchaser without restriction full and accurate information regarding numbers  for any known occurrences of infringement finished or semi-finished Products worldwide immediately upon learning of such infringements"

OR:

"Supplier shall also provide Purchaser without restriction full and accurate information regarding finished or semi-finished Products worldwide immediately upon learning of such infringements"

right?

thanks.

Comment: in outline the sentence is: Supplier (subject) provide (verb) information (direct object) [to] Purchaser (indirect object) immediately (adverbial).

Comment: is "numbers" also for "finished or semi-finished Products worldwide immediately upon learning of such infringements."

Comment: Someone has reformatted the example so that it no longer makes sense.

Comment: what?  is this "Supplier shall also provide Purchaser without restriction full and
 accurate information regarding finished or semi-finished Products worldwide
 immediately upon learning of such infringements" correct?"

Comment: Yes, that makes sense, though part of the original example seems to be missing.  The word "numbers" is not there, so I've lost track of what you are asking about.

Comment: but if is ""Supplier shall also provide Purchaser without restriction full and accurate information regarding finished or semi-finished Products worldwide immediately upon learning of such infringements""   , the meaning of "egarding finished or semi-finished Products worldwide " is werid.

Comment: The phrase "regarding finished or semi-finished Products world wide" modifies "information".  It is a reduced relative clause.  Without reduction, it would read "which regards finished ... world wide", where "which" refers to "information".

Answer (score 1):

I would say that it meant names and [contact] numbers - one example of where the Oxford comma helps make the sentence clear.

Comment: is this "Supplier shall also provide Purchaser without restriction full and accurate information regarding finished or semi-finished Products worldwide immediately upon learning of such infringements" correct?"   but if is ""Supplier shall also provide Purchaser without restriction full and accurate information regarding finished or semi-finished Products worldwide immediately upon learning of such infringements"" , the meaning of "egarding finished or semi-finished Products worldwide " is werid.

Comment: what's words OR phase in this sentence for " finished or semi-finished Products". thanks